# Swift Protocol - Dictionary property with values of any type

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a protocol with the following property:

```
var featureSpecificConfigurationDict: [String: Any] { get set }
```

It's a dictionary that should have a `String` as the key and can take any type as its value, i.e. `String`, `Int`, `Bool` etc

When I try to add a key and value to the dictionary in a class that conforms to the protocol as such:

```
var featureSpecificConfigurationDict = ["feature-specific-configuration" : "test"]
```

I get the following build error:

> Protocol requires property 'featureSpecificConfigurationDict' with
>   type '[String : Any]'

along with:

> Candidate has non-matching type '[String : String]'

I can cast the `String` key value to `Any` like below but that seems wrong to me.

```
var featureSpecificConfigurationDict = ["feature-specific-configuration" : "test" as Any]
```

So my question is, how do I correctly set a dictionary property in a protocol that accepts a value of any type and then use it in a class that conforms to that protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is looking at the dictionary you've provided and inferring that it's a `[String : String]`. If, in your class you declare `featureSpecificConfigurationDict` as

```
var featureSpecificConfigurationDict: [String : Any] = ["feature-specific-configuration" : "test"]
```

it'll realize that you want to be able to store `Any` type in there, not just those that it found in the initial value, and also conform to your protocol.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `var featureSpecificConfigurationDict = ["feature-specific-configuration" : "test"]` you give typecast job to the right side. So compiler thinking that it's `[String: String]`, you should handle type on the left side, so declare this with:

```
var featureSpecificConfigurationDict: [String : Any] = ["feature-specific-configuration" : "test"]
```

Answer (score 1):

String might be compatible with "Any", but [String:String] is not compatible with [String:Any]. Write

```
var featureSpecificConfigurationDict: [String:Any] = ["feature-specific-configuration" : "test"]
```